# backslashed json string to real json array in php

Tags: php

I have the following stored in my database:

```
"{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"sheep\":5,\"type\":\"test\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"title\":\"Sheep\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"title\":\"Hello\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"Car\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"title\":\"Car\"}"
```

But that's not a valid JSON string. How can I convert this string to a real Json array?

This is the code that is used:

```
$(document).on('click change', '.select-list', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = [];
    $('.optionitem').each(function(foo) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            options.push($(this).val());
        } else {
        }
    });
    $('#list').val(options);
    // This list is send via jQuery/Ajax to server and parsed like this when saving:
    // <?php $request['list'] = json_decode([$request['list']]); ?>
});
```

Comment: How do you get this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: I would suggest you fix the code that is storing this string to your database rather than trying to correct it now

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a PHP string with that as a value…

Running it through `json_decode` will convert it to a PHP string with a set of comma-separated JSON texts that represent objects.

Wrapping *that* with `[` and `]` and then running it through `json_decode` will convert it to a PHP array.

```
<?php
    $original_json = <<<END
    "{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"sheep\":5,\"type\":\"test\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"title\":\"Sheep\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"title\":\"Hello\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"Car\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"title\":\"Car\"}"
END;

    $json_one = "[" . json_decode($original_json, TRUE) . "]";
    $array = json_decode($json_one, TRUE);
    print_r($array);
?>
```

---

Your data is very broken. You should fix the code that generates it instead of hacking it into something sensible at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) or `echo`:

```
$json = "{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"sheep\":5,\"type\":\"test\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"title\":\"Sheep\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"title\":\"Hello\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"Car\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"title\":\"Car\"}";
echo stripslashes($json);
```

Technically, the slashes are for escaping. There are no slashes inside the content. If there was a slash, it would be represented as:

```
"{\"Hello\": \"World \\ Oven\"}"
```

Comment: @user1469734 How are you getting the data and how are you using it?

Comment: @user1469734 Did you try using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar — The question is tagged [tag:php], not [tag:javascript]

Comment: @Quentin Kindly look at the question, then talk. Thanks. `:D` `$(document).ready()` is jQuery, which is written in JavaScript and not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not a valid JSON to begin with. Let's say you put the string into a variable named `$data`:

```
$data = "[{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"sheep\":5,\"type\":\"test\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-20 17:51:41\",\"title\":\"Sheep\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Foobar\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-12-21 18:02:28\",\"title\":\"Hello\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"Car\",\"price\":5,\"type\":\"day\",\"created_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-03-16 11:16:59\",\"title\":\"Car\"}]";
```

Even if you strip the slashes, it will still not work:

```
json_decode(stripslashes($data)); // NULL
```

You should fix how the JSON is saved into the database to have a valid JSON to begin with. However, if you can't fix that, you could convert it to a valid JSON. It's missing the surrounding `[]`.

```
json_decode(sprintf('[%s]', stripslashes($data)));
```

### Output

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (7) { ["id"]=> int(10) ["name"]=> string(6) "Foobar" ["sheep"]=> int(5) ["type"]=> string(4) "test" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2017-12-20 17:51:41" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2017-12-20 17:51:41" ["title"]=> string(5) "Sheep" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (7) { ["id"]=> int(13) ["name"]=> string(6) "Foobar" ["price"]=> int(5) ["type"]=> string(3) "day" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2017-12-21 18:02:28" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2017-12-21 18:02:28" ["title"]=> string(5) "Hello" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#3 (7) { ["id"]=> int(15) ["name"]=> string(3) "Car" ["price"]=> int(5) ["type"]=> string(3) "day" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-03-16 11:16:59" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-03-16 11:16:59" ["title"]=> string(3) "Car" } }
```

More information about stripslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php